# Bodyweight glute training progression?

Tags: glutes

Squats have some decent bodyweight progression. But the squat is a vertical upward movement and the glutes deal with lateral and forward movements.

Hence why the squat is for hips and quads and the barbell hip trust for glutes.

Are there any decent progressions for glutes when it comes to bodyweight?

Comment: Decent bodyweight progression.. what do you mean, like they are good for you? Are you asking for bodyweight exercises for glutes?

Answer (score 1):

One of my favorite glute exercises with progression options are the bridge. You can do a simple bridge, then go to single leg, then elevate your legs, then elevate a single leg. Elevating your legs on an unstable surface (bosu ball) adds even more difficulty

There are other glute bodyweight exercises such as split squats. You can add a deficit or elevate your back leg to turn it into a Bulgarian split squat.

Another option are fire hydrants. This can start with a bent knee, then progressed to full leg extension, then you can add a band. Similar with glute kickbacks from a quadruped position.

Also keep in mind that you can make anything more challenging by adding a tempo and/or pause.